# What is “_ = variable” mean in sync/mutex.go

Tags: go, underline

sync/mutex.go:

```
func (m *Mutex) Unlock() {
    if race.Enabled {
         _ = m.state
         race.Release(unsafe.Pointer(m))
     }
...
```

### what's the mean of `_ = m.state`?

I know the `var _ interface = Object` mean check if `Object` implemented interface.

Comment: It forces the read of m.state.

Comment: Why read m.state but not use it?

Comment: To make the race detector work.

Answer (score 2):

From the commit log, the reason is  that "_ = m.state" make sure m is not nil.

```
commit 5bb3a66a973ea87494b9197091e8c1f122080627
Author: Rémy Oudompheng <oudomphe@phare.normalesup.org>
Date:   Mon Apr 8 23:46:54 2013 +0200

    sync, sync/atomic: do not corrupt race detector after a nil dereference.

    The race detector uses a global lock to analyze atomic
    operations. A panic in the middle of the code leaves the
    lock acquired.

    Similarly, the sync package may leave the race detectro
    inconsistent when methods are called on nil pointers.

    R=golang-dev, r, minux.ma, dvyukov, rsc, adg
    CC=golang-dev
    https://golang.org/cl/7981043
```

Answer (score 0):

To force the read of m.state and tick the race detector.